# Berkeley DB can't put then access data without closing db

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I'm trying to use berkeley DB to store and get simple key/data pairs but that doesn't work as I expected.
I create one function ( putdb() ) to put a key/data pair in the database and another ( getdb() ) to retrieve this pair.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <db.h>
DB *dbp;
void opendb(void)
{
        int ret; 
        if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0)
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "db.db", NULL,DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0)
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void putdb(const char *key, const char *value)
{
    DBT keyValue, dataValue;
    memset(&keyValue, 0, sizeof(keyValue));
    memset(&dataValue, 0, sizeof(dataValue));

    keyValue.size = sizeof(key);
    dataValue.size = sizeof(value);

    keyValue.data = malloc(keyValue.size);
    strcpy(keyValue.data,key);

    dataValue.data = malloc(dataValue.size);
    strcpy(dataValue.data,value);

    if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &keyValue, &dataValue, 0)) == 0)
            printf("db: %s: key stored.\n", (char *)keyValue.data);
    else {
            dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->put");
    }
    dbp->sync(dbp, 0);
}

void getdb(const char *key,const char *value)
{
    DBT keyValue, dataValue;
    memset(&keyValue, 0, sizeof(keyValue));
    memset(&dataValue, 0, sizeof(dataValue));

    keyValue.size = sizeof(key);
    dataValue.size = sizeof(value);

    keyValue.data = malloc(keyValue.size);
    strcpy(keyValue.data,key);

    dataValue.data = malloc(dataValue.size);
    strcpy(dataValue.data,value);

    if ((ret = dbp->get(dbp, NULL, &keyValue, &dataValue, 0)) == 0)
            printf("db: %s: key retrieved: data was %s.\n",
                (char *)keyValue.data, (char *)dataValue.data);
    else {
            dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->get");
    }
}
void closedb(void)
{
    dbp->close(dbp, 0);
    //TODO : error code return check
}
```

and the main file :

```
int main()
{
    opendb();
    putdb("toto","titi");
    getdb("toto","titi");
    closedb();
 }
```

and I get :

```
db: toto: key stored.
DB->get: BDB0073 DB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
```

Can you explain why ?

Notice if I change my main function :

```
int main()
{
    opendb();
    putdb("toto","titi");
    closedb();
    opendb();
    getdb("toto","titi");
    closedb();
}
```

then it works ! :

```
db: toto: key stored.
db: toto: key retrieved: data was titi.
```

Comment: Any reason you added the C++ tag?

Comment: If you're using a 32-bit platform, you're writing outside your allocations, which is Undefined Behaviour. On 64-bit architectures, you're reading uninitialised memory, which is also UB, and quite likely to result in key not found errors. In all cases you are leaking memory. You might want to fix those issues, even if it doesn't solve the immeduate problem (although it might).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have copied too much from the tutorial. They can use `sizeof("a string")` but you have to use `strlen(key)` in both `putdb` and `getdb`

```
keyValue.size = strlen(key);
dataValue.size = strlen(value);
```

Comment: Normally, you will not *provide* a data value when *retrieving* a key. `getdb("key", "value")` suggests that OP doesneedtoknow a bit more about data stores. :)

Comment: @rici yepp, as I noted "You have copied too much from the tutorial". Was that a bit too subtle?

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you are referring to, but if , for example, the malloc snd strcpy were copied, it is a very bad tutorial and should be put out of its misery at the earliest possible opportunity. Sadly, such antitutorials do exist, but I suspect that this is not a case of excessive copying but rather excessive elaboration, perhaps based on some previously assimilated cargo cult. In any case, the minimum antidote is probably a simple copyable example.

Comment: @rici I think it is from the official tutorial like the one found here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/reftoc.html (or a more recent version). I don't know what to make about the antidote but I think I'll give it a shot.

Comment: oO I feel ashamed of my error !! Of course I can't use sizeof on the pointers. Now it works. thanks you very much.

Comment: A lot of code that I write on my message come indeed from the official tutorial. malloc() and strcpy() doesn't come from the tutorial and are useful for other purpose(I didn't put all my code in the message) but it is completly useless here, I agree. I think the tutorial is good but my code was simply very bad.